# Why does strong duality apply here?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider the following LP $(P)$:
>
> $$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} x_1 + 2x_2 + \ldots + nx_n$$
>
> with
>
> \begin{align}
> x_1 &\ge 1 \\
> x_1 + x_2 &\ge 2 \\
> x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &\ge 3 \\
> &\vdots \\
> x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n &\ge n\\
> x_i \ge 0 \quad (\forall i)
> \end{align}
>
> Find the dual of $(P)$ and explain why strong duality applies here, i.e. there are solutions to
>   both problems and their optimal values are equal.

For a) I would suggest to add slack variables to obtain:

$$A := \begin{bmatrix}
&1 &0 &0 &0 &\ldots &0 &-1 &0 &0 &0\\
&1 &1 &0 &0 &\ldots &0 &0 &-1 &0 &0\\
&1 &1 &1 &0 &\ldots &0 &0 &0 &-1 &0\\
&\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\
&1 &1 &1 &1 &\ldots &1 &0 &0 &0 &-1\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then for 
$$b := c:= \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
\vdots \\
n
\end{bmatrix} $$

we have found the standardform of $(P)$:

$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}} \ c \cdot x \quad \text{ such that } \quad Ax = b \text{ and } x \ge 0$$

The dual of $(P)$ is thus

$$\max_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^m} \ b\lambda \quad \text{ such that } \quad A^T \lambda \le c.$$

Concernign the strong duality: I know that the existence of an optimal solution for one problem implies the existence of an optimal solution for the other and that both function values are then equal. However, I do not see how I could argue that $(P)$ or $(D)$ has an optimal solution. Could you help me?

Comment: If you are going to introduce slack variables, you need one *per constraint*, but you have introduced only one.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I will fix it.

Comment: Slater's condition is satisfied so strong duality holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspection, $(n,0,\dots,0)$ is optimal for $(P)$, with objective value $n$.  Now can you find a dual feasible solution that has the same objective value?  By complementary slackness, the dual constraint associated with $x_1$ will be satisfied with equality.